# How to get values from disabled form controls in a form group as Stream ? ( like the valueChanges method)

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

the regular behavior of Angular disabled FormControl inside a Form Group is to omit the key/value of the controller.
but I need to keep the structure of the form object result - so I need the key of the disables controller to appear inside the final form value object.

there is a simple solution to get it with the method "getRowValue()" but it is not a stream...
there is a built-in way to get it in a stream?

example

```
myForm = new FormGroup({   
    name:new FormControl({value:'',disabled:true}),
    power:new FormControl('')
  })
```

the result with valueChanges() {power:anyValue}

i need {power:anyValue ,name:""}

[example in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-yoni)

Answer (score 6):

Add something like this to your component:

```
rawValueChanges = this.myForm.valueChanges.pipe(
  map(_ => this.myForm.getRawValue())
)
```

See a [working example in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-yoni-zeqmdu)

Comment: how to do this with .subscribe()???

Comment: update.. just do this to subscribe (sad I didn't realize this until now)   `this.FormChangesSub = this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe((updatedForm: any) => {
     updatedForm = this.myForm.getRawValue()
...
}`

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to "save" the last state of your form in a property that you'll update each time your form is updated:

```js
  public formSave = null;

  ...

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (!this.formSave) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.formSave = this.myForm.value;
      });
    }

    this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(newVal => {
      console.log('changes', newVal);
      this.formSave = {...this.formSave, ...newVal};
    });
  }
```

Some explanations:

`{...this.formSave, ...newVal}` (called [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) takes the original saved form value (with your disabled value in case it has been disabled) and merges the new value returned by the `valueChanges` stream.

Why the `setTimeout()`? It's simply to avoid the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` since we're modifying a class property in a [lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks). So in order to trigger a new cycle check I'm putting the property initialization in this statement. But you also can fix this with a [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) (but this is off-topic).

Since only the enabled values are returned, it doesn't change the value(s) of the disabled field(s).

[Here's your working StackBlitz app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-yoni-kgdtfz)